# does any one knows why my laravel app.js disable some other js or jquery links

Tags: laravel

I am working on my collage project there is a problem with js links for example my bootstrap  drop menu will not work if i link laravel app.js. but if i remove the app.js file which is from laravel asset then other links works perfectly. I have change places of links but didn't work if someone please help me  Thanks [this is image of my footer file which include all js links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0pCa.jpg)

Comment: You need to share the error that what you are getting in console, please be specific to the problem

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception: $.material is undefined @http://sharepoint.div/js/material-dashboard.js:54:5
j@http://sharepoint.div/js/jquery.min.js:2:29997
g/</k<@http://sharepoint.div/js/jquery.min.js:2:30313
 undefined
jquery.min.js:2:31569
TypeError: $.material is undefined
////

Comment: thanks for replay the above error was there in console